# How do you get the time zone of a Redshift user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Where is the time zone of a Redshift user stored?

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in pg_user. But, there is no clean way to extract that info as far as I know. The below solution assumes there are less than 11 configs added to the user.

```
with uc as(
select
    distinct usename ,
    SPLIT_PART(useconfig, '=', 1) as name ,
    SPLIT_PART(useconfig, '=', 2) as value
from
    (
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[0]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[1]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[2]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[3]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[4]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[5]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[6]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[7]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[8]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[9]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null
union
    select
        usename,
        useconfig[10]::varchar(65535) useconfig
    from
        pg_user
    where
        useconfig is not null)
where
    useconfig is not null)
select
    *
from
    uc
where
    uc.name = 'TimeZone' ;
```